# Opening form a second time causes a run time error

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on vs2013 c# windows form. On `form1`, there is a button that, when clicked, takes user to the second form, `form2`. `Form2` would be a receipt for an in-house program, so it would need to be open more than just once. However, since I have `listboxes` on `form2` that has information taken form `form`1, the code:
`Form2 form2 = new Form2();` was written at class level instead of locally at the `button_click` event is. This causes a run time error every time I try to open form2 for the second time. This is the message I receive at where I wrote : `form2.show();`,

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll 
Additional information: Cannot access a disposed object.
```

How can I resolve this issue without moving the above mentioned code away from class level? Thank you.

Comment: Use `Hide` instead of `Close`.

Comment: Or use `ShowDialog` which does not dispose when you close (but do make sure to dispose as appropriate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might need a little more info, but.....

You might try to add an objekt in the constructror of form2.
Then bring in this object from Form1 with the data you need.

Like this (in form1):

Guest myGuest= new Guest();
Form2 form2 = new Form2(myGuest);

In form2:

Write a constructor like 
public form2(Guest thisGuest){}
create a object in Form2 (guest myGuest)

...and use a method like:
InitializeGUI(){ myGuest = thisGuest}

Hope it helps:)